# Cannot Compile .CS code in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to write quick console apps and compile them with VS 2010, but if I create a .cs file, then open it in VS 2010 (by simply double-clicking on the .cs file as these are registered by VS 2010), it opens, but there is no possible way to compile it.

e.g. here is some simplistic code:

```
using System;
public class Hello
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello C# World");
   }
}
```

I can compile this from the command line using    csc.exe hello.cs

But, if I can edit it in VS 2010, I should (sensibly) be able to compile it from the VS 2010 interface (plus debug, step through etc). In fact, although I can open and edit, it seems that Microsoft have made it impossible to compile in this way.

Could someone with knowledge of this please explain how to compile a simple .cs file from within the VS 2010 editor please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a project and solution to compile code in Visual Studio. Simply create a new C# Console Application, edit it, and run it.

Unless you elect to save the project/solution, VS can discard the entire thing. This is the best way to whip up quick example code.

**Updated**

I have a number of programs that are single-.cs files myself. When I want to tinker with them I simply create a new C# project and then add the file as a link. When I'm done tinkering, I close VS and choose discard. Because the .cs file was linked and not cloned, all changes are made to the original file. The discard only destroys the [temporary] project and solution files.

When I want to create something new, I create a new C# project and start writing. When I'm done, I use File -> Save As to save just the .cs file to a location where I keep all my single-source projects. I then discard the project/solution. Note that using File -> Save As creates a link so you don't have to wait until your done to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I will check SnippetCompiler sounds good. A *solution* seems a lot of complexity for a simple Hello World app. VS could be for both big-scale solutions and for console apps that do not require the rigidity of a full "solution". Instead just a .cs file, using VS as the fantastic IDE that it is, and compile a .cs to an .exe. I just don't get why Microsoft won't allow such an obvious and useful format (in addition to the full-scale "solution" system). dumbfounded by the wasted opportunity. if anyone knows a way to use C# in a script-like way like that would be appreciated ?

Comment: There already exists an alternative: Use the compiler from the command-line. Since there is already a way to get what you want (compiling sans solution/project files), there is no impulse for MS to change the structure of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

.cs files need to be part of a solution.

What you are looking for is Snippet Complier. This will allow you to compile small files very quickly.
http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/